# How do java fork -join frameworks allocate tasks onto a processor?

Tags: java, fork-join

Can anyone explain how java fork-join frameworks allocate tasks to a processor.  Can we control it ?

Comment: Are you talking about JSR-166?  AFAIK this hasn't been officially released yet, and what you're asking about will be some property of a specific implementation rather than the specification of the feature in the abstract.  So basically, I don't think your question is answerable right now.

Comment: Yes, I mean JSR-166, is there any documents might help ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on the OS

on solaris; you can bind processes or LWPs (threads) to a processor set (that can contain 1-n processors/cores)

on linux; you can bind a process to 1-n processors/core via [taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset)

don't know on windows

so the answer is theoretically yes on solaris, no on the other 2 platforms. For solaris, I think you'd need to call some jni to do the binding on thread creation. Alternatively, if you ensure the threads are started on startup and never get recycled during the life of the vm then you could start the process, wait n seconds then inspect the LWPs using `jstack`, find the threads you want and then bind those threads to predefined processor set via the nids (native ids) in the output of `jstack`. `poolbind` & `pooladm` & `poolcfg` are the relevant commands you need on solaris.

Comment: yes. The Q has 2 aspects, 1) how do you decide which thread a specific task runs on (not possible & doesn't really make sense anyway). 2) how do you decide which cpu a specific thread runs on? My reply answers the latter. If you have enough cores & run on solaris then you could setup a forkjoinpool that pins each thread to a single core and you may see a performance improvement as a result of that if it is a computationally expensive task (e.g. tasks not I/O bound at all).

Comment: Fair enough. I read this question as being about controlling affinity between tasks and threads, which is possible, and i think does make sense - the work-stealing idea is precisely about making tasks sticky to their creating thread, while not letting any thread slack off. But you're quite right, of course, that you can also control the affinity between the threads and the CPUs. You would need to do both to get the most out of the processor's caches.

Answer (score 1):

Fork join style frameworks usually use work stealing to schedule task. 
I.e. every thread has its own scheduler. And new task are enqueued in the same thread as they were created. Only when the queue of one thread's scheduler gets empty, it "steals" task, aka work, from another scheduler.

This is a obviously a simplification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems if we set thread-pool size equal to the number of processors we have say n, we will end up with n worker objects, I am interested in how each worker object maps onto different processor, can we control it ?

Comment: @koko: I don't really know, but my general knowledge about the Sun/Oracle JDK says probably no. At least not at the level of java threads. As Matt said, it is possible to  bind the whole process to certain processors.